# Call a PHP document repeatedly from the server side

Tags: php, server-side, intervals

I currently have a system where on the client side this Update function is called every X amount of seconds:

```
var Update = function(){
    $.getJSON("PHP/Update.php",{
        userid: userID },
        function(json){
               doSomething();
    });
}
```

In the PHP file some values are updated and these new values are sent back to the client.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $userid = $_GET['userid'];

    //Change some values in the database
    //Add these new values to $json array

    echo json_encode($json);
    mysqli_close($link);
?>'
```

This works great when there is exactly one client active at all time. Not so much when there are multiple or no clients active. So what I want is that this PHP files gets called once every X amount of time, regardless of how many clients there are. I realize I probably have to create a loop in PHP but I just can't get it working. Can anyone tell me how I'm supposed to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Time to start learning about [WebSockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)?  :)

Comment: @ghoti Actually, what he wants is most likely a cronjob to update the values and a second script just to read the values from the client.

Comment: I agree, though I still think it would be valuable to look at lower-impact solutions than having zillions of clients requesting database connections to be established.  I suppose another possibility would be for the PHP handler to check a last-update-time recorded in the db, and only update if it's older than "X amount of time".

Comment: Multiple clients all trying to update the same table at the same time over and over again doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: @ Danny. I realize that. Thats why I want to have this PHP file called every X amount of time from the server instead of the client. All the clients then get the new info each time the PHP file is called.

@ghoti. I will definitely look into that. But right now I'm just searching for an easy way to do this with PHP. Even if its not perfect.

@ Fred. You are right, the session_start() is useless at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you use to schedule things in unix-style operating systems is `cron`.  If your server runs MS Windows, you'll need to use some other scheduler.

There are a couple of ways that you can use `cron` to run your script.

First off, if you have a CLI version of PHP available (as opposed to an Apache module or a fcgi version), you can run it directly.  On my system, a cron job to run the script once per minute might look like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php
```

Note that on *your* system, the `php` binary might be located in `/usr/bin/` or `/opt/local/bin/` or somewhere else.  You'll need to check with your operating system's package repository to find out where, or type `which php` from a terminal.

If you use a "[shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)" at the beginning of your script, you can get away with a simpler cron job:

```
* * * * * /path/to/your/script.php
```

More information about running PHP shell scripts can be found [**here**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php).  A word of warning though...  If you launch scripts directly like this, they will run *as the user who owns the cron job*, which may have security (or at least permission) implications.  If you don't understand what this means, please ask more questions before doing it!

If you *don't* have a command line PHP available, you can still have the PHP script run via cron, by fetching it from a command-line HTTP client like `curl` or `wget` or `fetch` (depending on your operating system).  For example:

```
* * * * * curl -o /dev/null http://example.com/path/to/script.php
```

or

```
* * * * * wget -O /dev/null http://example.com/path/to/script.php
```

On a unix system you can `man crontab` for instructions on how to install cron jobs, and probably `man 5 crontab` (depending on your operating system) for instructions on the format for setting specific times.  Note that cron uses 1-minute granularity.  If you want greater frequency than that, you can fake it.  For example, for three times per minute:

```
* * * * * /path/to/your/script.php
* * * * * sleep 20; /path/to/your/script.php
* * * * * sleep 40; /path/to/your/script.php
```

And if you want lesser frequency, you use [crontab's documented format](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5). For example, every five minutes on weekdays but every 10 minutes on weekends:

```
*/5  * * * 1-5 /path/to/your/script.php
*/10 * * * 6-7 /path/to/your/script.php
```